# Register a script to be enqueued both in admin and front end

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

As i understand it, admin scripts are supposed to be registered and enqueued through the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook and all other scripts at `wp_enqueue_scripts` so i have set up the following functions to register and enqueue all my scripts in a clear and organized way.

My question is, what if i need certain scripts (eg. [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin) both in admin and on the front end? what is the recommended method for registering and enqueuing the script in this case? register it twice with diferent a $handle or register it through `wp_enqueue_scripts` only and if so, is there not the risk of it not being called when required ? (i mean, why else would `admin_enqueue_scripts` exist if not to make those scripts available at an earlier time?

I would really appreciate someone explain this to me to fully understand the nuances of enqueuing scripts in wp. Thanks

My code:

```
// REGISTER ALL NON-ADMIN SCRIPTS
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_all_non_admin_scripts' );
function register_all_non_admin_scripts() {

wp_register_script( ... );
wp_register_script( ... );

}

// ENQUEUE NON-ADMIN SCRIPTS CONDITIONALLY
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_where_required' );
function enqueue_scripts_where_required() {

// scripts to be loaded at all times
wp_enqueue_script( '' );

// scripts to be loaded conditionaly
if( is_page( '' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( '' );
}
}

// REGISTER ALL ADMIN SCRIPTS
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_all_admin_scripts' );
function register_all_admin_scripts(){
wp_register_script( ... );
wp_register_script( ... );
}

// ENQUEUE ADMIN SCRIPTS
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_contact_cpt_js' );
function enqueue_admin_contact_cpt_js(){

global $post_type;

// scripts to be loaded at all times
wp_enqueue_script( '' );

// scripts to be loaded conditionaly by post type
if( 'contact' == $post_type ){
    wp_enqueue_script( '' );
    ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can *register* the scripts earlier, for example on `wp_loaded`:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'register_all_scripts' );

function register_all_scripts() 
{
    wp_register_script(...);
}
```

And then you *enqueue* the scripts whenever you need them:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_front_scripts' );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_back_scripts' );
```

Use the same handles and names to avoid collisions with other scripts.

Comment: i guess that would solve the problem for the scripts to be used in both admin and front end yes; i'll add another function for these cases. thanks @toscho

Answer (score 1):

You can also use one hook to include common assets, instead of calling hook for admin and frontend separately like

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'enque_common_scripts' );
function enque_common_scripts()
{
  wp_enqueue_style(...);
  wp_enqueue_script(...);
}
```